# Add ionic-spinner programmatically

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a directive called ImgCache (which is self explanatory).

Right now I'm showing a blank space where the image will be, while it's being downloaded and stored. I want to show a `<ion-spinner></ion-spinner>` inside of this placeholder to indicate the Image will be shown shortly.

I'm adding it from the directive, programmatically like this:

```
this.el.nativeElement.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `
    <div style="width;height;etc">
        <ion-spinner></ion-spinner>
    </div>
`)
```

but the ion-spinner is now showing. Using AngularJS I had to do something like this: `$compile(element.contents())(scope)`

What is the equivalent in Angular (4)

Comment: I would put the <ion-spinner> directly inside the template and show/hide it with an ngIf  on a condition that would be set to the loaded image state

Comment: This means I would have to change everywhere in my code where I use my ImgCache directive.